# sklearn: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples when calling LinearRegression.fit()

Tags: scikit-learn

Just trying to do a simple linear regression but I'm baffled by this error for:

```
regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(df2.iloc[1:1000, 5].values, df2.iloc[1:1000, 2].values)
```

which produces:

```
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1 999]
```

These selections must have the same dimensions, and they should be numpy arrays, so what am I missing?

Comment: i did reshape(-1,1) and it worked

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It looks like sklearn requires the data shape of (row number, column number). 
If your data shape is (row number, ) like `(999, )`, it does not work. 
By using `numpy.reshape()`, you should change the shape of the array to `(999, 1)`, e.g. using

```
data=data.reshape((999,1))
```

In my case, it worked with that.

Comment: my data shape is (10L,), how do i convert it to (10L,1). When i use data=data.reshape(len(data),1), the resulting shape is (10L,1L) not (10L,1)

Comment: @user3841581 please refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40440997/4896087).

Comment: @Boern Thanks for the comment. I also discovered that X_train should be of size (N,1) but y_train should be of size (N,) not (N,1), otherwise it does not work, at least not for me.

Comment: data.reshape(...) may show deprication warning if data is Series object. Use data.values.reshape(...)

Comment: data  = data.reshape(-1,1)

Answer (score 25):

Looks like you are using pandas dataframe (from the name df2).

You could also do the following:

```
regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(df2.iloc[1:1000, 5].to_frame(), df2.iloc[1:1000, 2].to_frame())
```

NOTE: I have removed "values" as that converts the pandas Series to numpy.ndarray and numpy.ndarray does not have attribute to_frame().

Answer (score 14):

Seen on the Udacity deep learning foundation course:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
...
regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(df[['column x']], df[['column y']])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really the simplest and easiest to understand!

Comment: Actually, the Y parameter is expected as a (length, ) shape. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think the "X" argument of regr.fit needs to be a matrix, so the following should work.

```
regr = LinearRegression()
regr.fit(df2.iloc[1:1000, [5]].values, df2.iloc[1:1000, 2].values)
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this error because I converted my data to an `np.array`. I fixed the problem by converting my data to an `np.matrix` instead and taking the transpose.

ValueError:
`regr.fit(np.array(x_list), np.array(y_list))`

Correct: 
`regr.fit(np.transpose(np.matrix(x_list)), np.transpose(np.matrix(y_list)))`

Answer (score 3):

```
expects X(feature matrix)
```

Try to put your features in a tuple like this:

```
features = ['TV', 'Radio', 'Newspaper']
X = data[features]
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. The problem in my case was, Number of rows in X was not equal to number of rows in y.

i.e. number of entries in feature columns was not equal to number of entires in target variable since I had dropped some rows from freature columns.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze two arrays (array1 and array2) they need to meet the following two requirements:

**1) They need to be a numpy.ndarray**

Check with

```
type(array1)
# and
type(array2)
```

If that is not the case for at least one of them perform

```
array1 = numpy.ndarray(array1)
# or
array2 = numpy.ndarray(array2)
```

**2) The dimensions need to be as follows:**

```
array1.shape #shall give (N, 1)
array2.shape #shall give (N,)
```

N is the number of items that are in the array.
To provide array1 with the right number of axes perform:

```
array1 = array1[:, numpy.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned above X argument must be a matrix or a numpy array with known dimensions. So you could probably use this:

```
df2.iloc[1:1000, 5:some_last_index].values
```

So your dataframe would be converted to an array with known dimensions and you won't need to reshape it

Answer (score 0):

during train test split you might have done a mistake

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X,Y,test_size)
```

The above code is correct

You might have done like below which is wrong

```
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X,Y,test_size)
```