# Python 2.7/ Scikit learn 0.17 Linear Regression error: ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 343]

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn

I am reading a csv and try to take make a linear regression model based on  df['LSTAT'] (x/variable) v.s. df['MEDV'] (y/target). However, the error message " ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1 343]" keeps poping out during the model fitting stage.

I have shape/re-shape the data (not sure if I have done correctly) or transform the pd.DataFrame into numpy arrays and lists.  None of them works. I still don't quite understand the issue after reading this post: [sklearn: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples when calling LinearRegression.fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre)  .  The scripts and the error messages are below.

Could any guru offer some solutions with detailed explanations? Thank you!

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import pylab 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import sklearn
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


df=pd.read_csv("input.csv")


X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(df['LSTAT'],df['MEDV'],test_size=0.3,random_state=1)

lin=LinearRegression()

################## This line: " lin_train=lin.fit(X_train1,y_train1)" causes the trouble. 

lin_train=lin.fit(X_train1,y_train1)

################## The followings are just the plotting lines after fitting the Linear regression

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', lin.coef_)
# The mean square error
print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
      % np.mean((lin.predict(X_test1) - y_test1) ** 2))
# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.2f' % lin.score(X_test1, y_test1))

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(X_test1, y_test1,  color='black')
plt.plot(X_test1, lin.predict(X_test1), color='blue',linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Here is the warning & error message:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 386
    DeprecationWarning)
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pin-Chih/Google Drive/Real_estate_projects/test.py", line 36, in <module>
    lin_train=lin.fit(X_train1,y_train1)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 427, in fit
    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 520, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 176, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1 343]>>>
```

If I print out the "x_train1":

```
X_train1:  
61     26.82
294    12.86
39     29.29
458     4.85
412     8.05
Name: LSTAT, dtype: float64
```

If I print out the "y_train1":

```
y_train1:  
61     13.4
294    22.5
39     11.8
458    35.1
412    29.0
Name: MEDV, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not a guru but I've had similar problems in the past because the model is expecting the X argument to have at least 2 dimensions, even if the second dimension is 1. The first thing I would try would be to replace

`lin_train=lin.fit(X_train1,y_train1)`

with

`lin_train=lin.fit(X_train1.reshape(X_train1.shape[0], 1), y_train1)`

which should give you data with shape (343, 1) rather than just 343.

Comment: Thank you guru the mi_dominic! But I don't quite understand the meaning of "1" here in (343,1).  It is just a dummy variable/value?  Moreover, if we check the scikit learn example here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html   "print diabetes_X_train" will only give us  [ 0.05415152] [-0.00836158] etc., which is one dimensional. So I guess the model can take 1 dimension data? Please let me know if I am wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: I think of it as a 343 x 1 dimensional array rather than just a series of 343 elements, but you're right; it should be the same thing. The documentation says that X should be an array in the format [n_samples, n_features] and y should be [n_samples, n_targets], but it seems that it will assume 1 for n_targets for y if not specified, but forces you to specify n_features for X.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks for your answer! But I have to say that the Scikit learn manual is not very clear and make it kinda hard to understand.  Statsmodel and examples are way much clearer!