# KNeighborsClassifier .predict() function doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

i am working with KNeighborsClassifier algorithm from scikit-learn library in Python. I followed basic instructions e.g.  split my data and labels into training and test data, then trained my model on a training data. Now I am trying to predict accuracy of testing data but get an error. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

 data_train, data_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(df, labels, 
                                                              test_size=0.2,
                                                              random_state=7)
mod = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)
mod.fit(data_train, label_train)
predictions = mod.predict(data_test)

print accuracy_score(label_train, predictions)
```

The error I get:

```
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [140 558]
```

140 is the portion of training data and 558 is the test data based on the test_size=0.2 (my data set is 698 samples). I verified that labels and data sets are of the same size 698. However, I get this error which is basically trying to compare test data and training data sets.

Does anyone knows what is wrong here? What should I use to train my model against to and what should I use to predict the score?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate the `accuracy_score` with `label_test`, not `label_train`. You want to compare the actual labels of the test set, `label_test`, to the predictions from your model, `predictions`, for the test set.

Comment: Thank you @Igaud ! It did work! Now when I am looking at documentation it is kind of obvious. I happen to follow the mistake that was made in tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to solve your issue via the following question ?

> [sklearn: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples when calling LinearRegression.fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I tried reshaping my data with a following code:

`label_train = np.reshape(label_train, (len(label_train), 1))`
`label_test = np.reshape(label_test, (len(label_test), 1))`
`print label_train.shape`
`print data_train.shape`
`print data_test.shape`
`print label_test.shape`

here is what I get for result:
`(558, 1)`
`(558, 2)`
`(140, 2)`
`(140, 1)`

And still the same error:

`ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [140 558]`