# How to change the shape of a Pandas Dataframe (row number with an "L")?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a one column pandas dataframe of the shape `(362L,)`, and would like to change it to `(362, 103)`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured out, since the object of the shape `(362L,)` is really a pandas series, I just need to change it to dataframe, like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(df)
```

That's it!

Comment: You can also use `to_frame` method (`ser.to_frame()`). Optionally, you can pass a name for the single column: `ser.to_frame('col_name')`.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
df.iloc[:, 0].apply(pd.Series)
```