# Why is scikit learn's average precision score returning nan?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, keras

My Keras model is designed to take in two input time series, concatenate them, feed them through an LSTM, and do multilabel prediction on the next time step.

There are 50 training samples, with 24 time steps each, and 5625 labels each.

There are 12 validation samples, with 24 time steps each, and 5625 labels each.

When I try to validate the model, I get 'nan' for `average_precision_score`. Why?

I've prepared an MWE below, illustrating the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Concatenate, multiply
from keras import optimizers
import tensorflow as tf

def model_definition():
        tr_hours, val_hours = [], []
        for i in np.arange(a_tr.shape[0]):
                for j in np.arange(a_tr.shape[1]):
                        tr_hours.append(i+j)
        for i in np.arange(a_val.shape[0]):
                for j in np.arange(a_val.shape[1]):
                        val_hours.append(i+j)
        tr_hours = np.asarray(tr_hours).reshape(a_tr.shape[0], a_tr.shape[1], 1)
        val_hours = np.asarray(val_hours).reshape(a_val.shape[0], a_val.shape[1], 1)
        num_time = a_tr.shape[2] + tr_hours.shape[2]
        hours_in = Input(shape=(1,), batch_shape = (1, 1, tr_hours.shape[2]), name='hours_in')
        seq_model_in = Input(shape=(1,), batch_shape=(1, 1, a_tr.shape[2]), name='seq_model_in')
        t_concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([seq_model_in, hours_in])
        lstm_layer = LSTM(4, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, num_time), stateful=True)(t_concat)
        dense_merged = Dense(a_tr.shape[2], activation="sigmoid", name='dense_after_lstm')(lstm_layer)
        model = Model(inputs=[seq_model_in, hours_in], outputs=dense_merged)
        return tr_hours, val_hours, model


def train_and_validate(a_tr, a_old_tr, a_val, a_old_val):
        a_tr = a_tr[:, :-1, :]
        y_tr = a_tr[:, -1, :]
        a_val = a_val[:, :-1, :]
        y_val = a_val[:, -1, :]
        a_old_tr = a_old_tr[:, :-1, :]
        y_old_val = a_old_val[:, -1, :]
        y_old_tr = a_old_tr[:, -1, :]
        seq_length = a_tr.shape[1]
        tr_hours, val_hours, model = model_definition()
        print model.summary()
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        #http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/
        #TRAINING
        for epoch in range(1): #one epoch for demo purposes
                mean_tr_loss,  mean_val_ap = [], []
                for i in range(a_tr.shape[0]):
                        y_true_1 = np.expand_dims(y_tr[i,:], axis=1)
                        y_true = np.swapaxes(y_true_1, 0, 1)
                        for j in range(seq_length-1):
                                input_1 = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(a_tr[i][j], axis=1), axis=1)
                                input_1 = np.reshape(input_1, (1, 1, a_tr.shape[2]))
                                input_2 = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(np.array([tr_hours[i][j]]), axis=1), axis=1)
                                input_2 = np.reshape(input_2, (1, 1, tr_hours.shape[2]))
                                tr_loss = model.train_on_batch([input_1, input_2], y_true)
                                mean_tr_loss.append(tr_loss)
                        model.reset_states()
                print('loss training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_loss)))
                #VALIDATION MWE
                print 'validating, first sample only'
                val_y_1 = np.expand_dims(y_val[0,:], axis=1)
                val_y = np.swapaxes(val_y_1, 0, 1)
                y_val_true = np.expand_dims(y_old_val[0,:], axis=1)
                y_val_true = np.swapaxes(y_val_true, 0, 1)
                val_seq = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(a_val[0][22], axis=1), axis=1)
                val_seq = np.reshape(val_seq, (1, 1, a_val.shape[2]))
                val_hours_use = np.expand_dims(np.array([val_hours[0][22]]), axis=1)
                val_pred = model.predict_on_batch([val_seq, val_hours_use])
                val_ap = average_precision_score(y_val_true, val_pred)
                print 'validation average precision: ', val_ap
                model.reset_states()
        return val_ap


if __name__=='__main__':

    a_tr = np.random.uniform(size=(50, 24, 5625))
    a_old_tr = np.random.uniform(size=(50, 24, 5625))
    a_val = np.random.uniform(size=(12, 24, 5625))
    a_old_val = np.random.uniform(size=(50, 24, 5625))
    a_test = np.random.uniform(size=(12, 24, 5625))
    a_old_test = np.random.uniform(size=(50, 24, 5625))
    a_old_tr[a_old_tr > 0.5] = 1.
    a_old_tr[a_old_tr < 0.5] = 0.
    a_old_val[a_old_val > 0.5] = 1.
    a_old_val[a_old_val < 0.5] = 0.

    train_and_validate(a_tr, a_old_tr, a_val, a_old_val)
```

Running the above code should give you something like this, in less than 30 seconds. Note average precision returns nan:

```
    user@server:~/path/to/curr/dir$ python dummy_so.py 
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
    ==================================================================================================
    seq_model_in (InputLayer)       (1, 1, 5625)         0                                            
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    hours_in (InputLayer)           (1, 1, 1)            0                                            
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (1, 1, 5626)         0           seq_model_in[0][0]               
                                                                     hours_in[0][0]                   
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (1, 4)               90096       concatenate_1[0][0]              
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    dense_after_lstm (Dense)        (1, 5625)            28125       lstm_1[0][0]                     
    ==================================================================================================
    Total params: 118,221
    Trainable params: 118,221
    Non-trainable params: 0
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    None
    2018-01-24 13:43:24.873725: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
    loss training = 0.346308231354
    validating, first sample only
    validation average precision:  nan
    user@server:~/path/to/curr/dir$
```

The same error is occurring even with a simpler model, with only one input:

```
def train_and_validate(a_tr, a_old_tr, a_val, a_old_val):
        a_tr = a_tr[:, :-1, :]
        y_tr = a_tr[:, -1, :]
        a_val = a_val[:, :-1, :]
        y_val = a_val[:, -1, :]
        a_old_tr = a_old_tr[:, :-1, :]
        y_old_val = a_old_val[:, -1, :]
        y_old_tr = a_old_tr[:, -1, :]
        seq_length = a_tr.shape[1]

        #Define the model
        seq_model_in = Input(shape=(1,), batch_shape=(1, 1, a_tr.shape[2]), name='seq_model_in')
        lstm_layer = LSTM(4, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, a_tr.shape[2]), stateful=True)(seq_model_in)
        dense_merged = Dense(a_tr.shape[2], activation="sigmoid", name='dense_after_lstm')(lstm_layer)
        model = Model(inputs=seq_model_in, outputs=dense_merged)
        print model.summary()
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        #http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/
        #TRAINING (one epoch, for demo purposes)
        mean_tr_loss,  mean_val_ap = [], []
        for i in range(a_tr.shape[0]):
                y_true_1 = np.expand_dims(y_tr[i,:], axis=1) 
                y_true = np.swapaxes(y_true_1, 0, 1)
                for j in range(seq_length-1):
                        input_1 = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(a_tr[i][j], axis=1), axis=1) 
                        input_1 = np.reshape(input_1, (1, 1, a_tr.shape[2]))
                        tr_loss = model.train_on_batch(input_1, y_true) 
                        mean_tr_loss.append(tr_loss)
                model.reset_states()
        print('loss training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_loss)))
        #VALIDATION MWE
        print 'validating, first sample only'
        val_y_1 = np.expand_dims(y_val[0,:], axis=1) 
        val_y = np.swapaxes(val_y_1, 0, 1)
        y_val_true = np.expand_dims(y_old_val[0,:], axis=1) 
        y_val_true = np.swapaxes(y_val_true, 0, 1)
        val_seq = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(a_val[0][22], axis=1), axis=1) 
        val_seq = np.reshape(val_seq, (1, 1, a_val.shape[2]))
        val_pred = model.predict_on_batch(val_seq)
        val_ap = average_precision_score(y_val_true, val_pred)
        print 'validation average precision: ', val_ap
        model.reset_states()
        return val_ap
```

Comment: Could you check do you have `nan`s in your predictions?

Comment: I did, using this: `print 'whether there are nans here', np.isnan(val_pred).any()`. It returned False.

Comment: Ok - so can you check histograms of true classes in `y_val_true` predictions?

Comment: I have highly unbalanced data. Each of the 5625 possible labels is either 0 or 1, with the vast majority being 0. What do you mean by histograms of the true classes in the predictions?

Comment: You could have only one class in validation set.

Comment: I checked that quickly by doing `print np.where(a_old_val == 0.)` and with 1. as well. Both gave an array of indices, so I'm thinking there's more than one class in the validation set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163826/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-statssorceress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lied in wrong (inversed) dimensions. Flattening matrices did the job:

```
y_val_true, val_pred = y_val_true.reshape((-1)), val_pred.reshape((-1))
val_ap = average_precision_score(y_val_true, val_pred)
```

Comment: For any new readers: if you're doing this in conjunction with hyperopt, you may need to only reshape in average_precision_score itself, like this: `val_ap = average_precision_score(y_val_true.reshape((-1)), val_pred.reshape((-1)))`, to avoid problems like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre