# ValueError in using .fit()

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to perform a simple linear regression as follows

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(1,769)
data=np.genfromtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv',delimiter=',')
y=np.sort(data[:,4])
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)
```

I am getting the following ValueError

```
ValueError:Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 768]
```

I even tried reshaping my X as

```
X.reshape(-1,1)
```

But it doesn't help.Where am I wrong?

Comment: can you print shape of `x` and `y` before passing them to the fit?

Comment: its (768,) for both x and y

Comment: then this seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre

Comment: But the accepted solution doesn't work for me..I already looked it up

Comment: Did you print out the shapes after reshaping to make sure they are what you expect?

Comment: `x` must be a matrix, not a vector. Try passing `x[:,np.newaxis]` instead of `x` to the function. `x.reshape(-1,1)` must have helped, too. How exactly "it doesn't help"?

Comment: I've used x.reshape(-1,1) and then printed out the shape..it did not change, but when I printed out x it looked exactly how I wanted it to be.But then I tried x.shape=((768,1)),it worked for me.Why did this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sklearn: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples when calling LinearRegression.fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre)

Comment: I just found out that x.reshape(-1,1) is returning a copy, without modifying x.It works though if I used x=x.reshape(-1,1) instead