# Sklearn cross_val_score with multi input KerasClassifier

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

The goal is to perform cross validation on a Keras model with multiple inputs. This works fine with a normal sequential model with only one input. However, when using the functional api and extending to two inputs sklearns `cross_val_score` does not seem to work as expected.

```
def create_model():
    input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    embedding = Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512, ))(input_text)
    dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(embedding)

    input_title = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    embedding_title = Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(512, ))(input_title)
    dense_title = Dense(256, activation='relu')(embedding_title)

    out = Concatenate()([dense, dense_title])

    pred = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(out)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_text, input_title], outputs=pred)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

#### part that fails

```
keras_classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=0)
results = cross_val_score(keras_classifier, [X1, X2], y, cv=cv, scoring='f1_weighted')
```

#### error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "func.py", line 73, in <module>
    results = cross_val_score(keras_classifier, [X1, X2], y, cv=cv, scoring='f1_weighted')
  File "/home/timisb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 402, in cross_val_score
    error_score=error_score)
  File "/home/timisb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 225, in cross_validate
    X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
  File "/home/timisb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 260, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/home/timisb/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 643]
```

Does anyone have an alternative approach to this, or suggestions of a solution? Thanks!

Comment: here the workaround to pass multiple inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824968/grid-search-for-keras-with-multiple-inputs/62512554#62512554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason which is below.

> You can use Sequential Keras models (single-input only) as part of
>   your Scikit-Learn workflow via the wrappers found at
>   keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.py.

https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/

Comment: here the workaround to pass multiple inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824968/grid-search-for-keras-with-multiple-inputs/62512554#62512554

Answer (score 5):

You could run your own cross validation implementation. Example CV implementation could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

input_1 = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
input_2 = [[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]]
Y = [[0], [0], [0], [2], [2], [0], [1], [1], [2], [0]]

# Split a dataset into k folds
def cross_validation_split(X1, X2, Y, folds=4):
    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4, shuffle = True)
    skf.get_n_splits(X1, Y)
    dataset_split = []
    i = 0
    for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X1, Y):
        print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
        train_index = train_index.astype(int)
        test_index = test_index.astype(int)
        X1 = np.array(X1)
        X2 = np.array(X2)
        Y = np.array(Y)
        X_1_train, X_1_test = X1[train_index], X1[test_index]
        X_2_train, X_2_test = X2[train_index], X2[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
        k_fold_set = {
                    'k_fold': i,
                    'train': {'X_1': X_1_train, 'X_2': X_2_train, 'Y': y_train},
                    'test': {'X_1': X_1_test, 'X_2': X_2_test, 'Y': y_test}
                    }
        dataset_split.append(k_fold_set)
        i = i + 1

    return dataset_split

result = cross_validation_split(input_1, input_2, Y, folds=4)
```

Then simply loop over the created `result` list and perform your training/validation logic and save the results into a list which will have the results for you k-fold cross validation.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `cross_val_score` function from the `scikit-learn` indicating the `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 643]`

It looks like sklearn requires the different data [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre).

You could use `data.reshape()`.

General tip:
First, I think the cross validation is generally an indicator of "not having enough training data". Keras and generally TensorFlow team did not pay to much attention to provide CV features.

Comment: Indeed I dont have a lot of data. I am using Transfer Learning. Where could I reshape the data, could you provide an example?