# sklearn: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples when calling naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, text-classification, naivebayes

I have looked at similar questions as such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre). But none of the mentioned solutions worked in my case.

I am trying to build a text classification prediction model.

```
def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, is_neural_net=False):
    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)

    # predict the labels on validation dataset
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)

    if is_neural_net:
        predictions = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)

    return metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, train_label)

# Naive Bayes on Word Level TF IDF Vectors
accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(),train_text,train_label,test_text)

print ("NB, WordLevel TF-IDF: ", accuracy)
```

However, Naive_bayes returns the below error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [500, 3100]
```

my training data

```
print(train_text.shape)
type(train_text)
```

returns

```
(3100, 3013)
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

my training labels

```
print(train_label.shape)
type(train_label)
```

returns

```
(3100,)
numpy.ndarray
```

my test dataset

```
print(test_text.shape)
type(test_text)
```

returns

```
(500, 3013)
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

I tried every possible type of transformation. Can any one recommend a solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in

```
predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)
return metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, train_label)
```

What is the shape of predictions? Is `train_label` a global variable in `train_model`? Also, is `prediction` has the same shape as `train_label`?

Comment: The shape of prediction is `(500,)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. The shape of `train_label` is `(3100,)`. How do you calculate the accuracy of `predictions` and `train_label` when they have different shape?

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: You can either `predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_train)` or `metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, valid_label)` if you have validation set has label.

Comment: It worked when I replaced feature_vector_valid with feature_vector_train. But is is the right approach? because I am following this guide https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/ and that is where I got my code from. Can I see the predicted output? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because the predictions should be made based on the test data, not the training data.

Comment: Oh I see. Of course you should not make prediction based on train data. But I see you copy the wrong code. It should be `metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, valid_y)`, but you wrote `metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, train_label)`.

Comment: because this is the name of my train_label. It is different from the one in the link.

Comment: No, that's not how accuracy works. I think you misundestand accuracy. Accuracy only works when two arguments have the same shape.  That's why you should compare `prediction` (shape 500) with `valid_y` (shape 500) instead of `train_label` (shape 3100). `metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, valid_y)` is correct. `metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, train_label)` is just wrong.

Comment: I don't know what is the corresponding value to valid_y in my data.

Comment: `valid_y` is just your test label. You have `train_text,train_label,test_text`, so I guess you have something like `test_label`? If you have it, try `metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, test_label)`

Comment: I don't have it because this is a prediction model. So `train_text` is 3100 tweets. `train_label` is 3100 gender of the users. `train_text` is 500 tweets and the model is supposed to predict 500 genders.

Comment: The purpose of accuracy score is to compare the prediction with the true label, to see how many correct prediction. But if you only have prediction but not the true label, you cannot use accuracy sore.