# Confusion matrix - variables with inconsistent number of samples

Tags: scikit-learn

Supervised learning with numeric data applying KNN classifier giving an error while I am calling *metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)*. The conducting error message is: ***Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [40000, 2000]***. Thanks in advance for showing lights.

Comment: You should check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre)

Answer (score 0):

The confusion matrix compares the values in both arrays and basically tells how many samples were labelled same and how many differed in both of them. For this, the number of elements in both arrays should be the same. This is what the error says.

So make sure that both of them have same number of elements.

Perhaps if you include previous code that deals with y_test and y_pred, it would be easier to see why the sizes are different.